# Rails: Running more than one rake task at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Been loving rails, but still struggling with how long it takes to run tasks from the command line.

I'm wondering if it's possible to combine multiple rake tasks without reloading the environment each time. For example, if I run

```
rails generate rspec:install && rails generate model test_model title:string && rake db:migrate
```

it will spend 10 seconds loading up rails to run the rspec install, then another ten seconds to load up the environment for generate model, then another for the migration. Is there a way to keep the same environment open for all 3 commands?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Take a look at the [rails-sh](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-sh) gem - it boots the Rails environment, and then presents a command line interface, so you can run your command within it.  There are limitations when using it (I don't think you can change your RAILS_ENV), but for your use-case, it should be perfect.

If your commands are just rake tasks, you can use spaces to separate them, e.g.:

```
rake db:migrate && rake db:test:clone_structure
```

would become

```
rake db:migrate db:test:clone_structure
```

Comment: Note: separating Rake tasks with spaces seems to act like the Bash operator `&&`, as the answer implies – not the `;` operator. Space-separating only runs a task if the previous tasks finished without error. `bundle exec rake test cucumber` only runs the `cucumber` task if no tests failed during the `test` task.

Comment: Space-separating isn’t exactly equivalent to `&&`, either. In one version of my code, `bundle exec rake test cucumber` makes some Cucumber tests fail, but `bundle exec rake test && bundle exec rake cucumber` lets all tests pass. (It may be related to how `bundle exec cucumber` (without `rake`) on that version of the code sometimes, but not always, also makes some tests fail.)

Comment: rails-sh [last commit](https://github.com/jugyo/rails-sh/commits/master) is from 2012 :( Looks like it's only [compatible with rails 3](https://github.com/jugyo/rails-sh#rails-sh)